# ASP.NET Boilerplate MySql ApplySoftDeleteFilter

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, ef-core-2.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I switch database of existing ASP.NET Boilerplate project from MS SQL to MySql. I have used Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql. While switching I test that soft delete is working but when I call GetAll or GetAllIncluding methods over Repository, ApplySoftDeleteFilter not working. What could be a problem?

Comment: What is the current and expected behavior? Show relevant code.

Comment: @aaron no exception. Just when calling Repository.GetAllIncluding() method, IsDeteled=True rows also returned. But when use MS SQL database, all are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

try to update to the latest ABP version.
And capture the t-sql to see what's running in MySql server.

Comment: I update latest ABP but did not help. I capture LINQ generated SQL, but there is no condition for "IsDeleted != true";

Comment: Alper I look at both MS SQL and My SQL generated SQLs. They differ. For MS SQL queries it consider IsDeleted = 0, but for MySQL queries did not. What could be a problem. Have you checked ABP framework core version with MySQL?